# script for logging all the stats for a particular process

Tags: shell-script, centos, monitoring, cpu, io

I want to monitor CPU usage, disk read/write usage for a particular process, say `./myprocess`.

To monitor CPU `top` command seems to be a nice option and for read and write `iotop` seems to be a handy one.

For example to monitor read/write for every second i use the command `iotop -tbod1 | grep "myprocess"`.

My difficulty is I just want only three variables to store, namely read/sec, write/sec, cpu usage/sec. Could you help me with a script that combines the outputs the above said three variables from `top` and `iotop` to be stored into a log file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about [PidStat](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-monitor-process-on-linux-using.html)?. Have you tried it? You may need the Pid for the process you want to monitor, but that should be fairly easy to get with the `ps` command and a bit of `awk` chop-chopping.

It's part of the package `sysstat` which you can install in .deb based systems by typing `apt-get install sysstat`

Comment: I'm using centOS and `pidstat` doesn't seem to come with `sysstat`.

Comment: Mmmm... That's a bit weird... In CentOS 6.2 (Final), I get this with a `yum whatprovides */pidstat` outputs:
`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: centos.mirror.nac.net
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * updates: mirror.us.leaseweb.net
sysstat-9.0.4-18.el6.x86_64 : The sar and iostat system monitoring commands
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/pidstat

perl-IPC-Locker-1.484-1.el6.rf.noarch Repo: rpmforge
Filename    : /usr/bin/pidstat` What CentOS and repositories are you using?

Comment: I'm using `centOS5` and `yum whatprovides */pidstat` outputs `No mathes Found`

Comment: I'm afraid I have nothing, then... sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use prtstat (`sudo apt-get install psmisc`):

```
watch -n1 prtstat <PID> | tee mylog.log
```

it'll dump the process statistics every second.
If you're interested in parsing those data, use the raw version (-r).

In example, if you want utime, you can extend above command to:

```
prtstat -r 30557 | grep -w utime | awk '{print $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [audria](https://github.com/scaidermern/audria) for this task:

```
audria -d 1 $(pidof myprocess) | awk -F "," '{print $7, $28, $32}'
```

This will set the delay to *1* second, monitor *myprocess* and print the current *CPU* (field 7), *read bytes/s* (field 28) and *write bytes/s* (field 32). The read/write counters here exclude cached bytes, if you want to include them choose fields *26* and *30* instead.

audria is also capable of executing your process to monitor it right from the start if required. You can also choose a shorter interval or specify multiple PIDs to watch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the contents of `/proc/$PID/status` periodically; that should give you a fair amount of the information you're looking for.

Comment: Additionally there is `/proc/$PID/io`.